# Qt QPainter in millimetres instead of inches

Tags: c++, qt, printing, transform

I have a QPrinter that prints A4 either directly to a physical printer or a PDF. Now I'd like to use QPainter to draw in millimetres, but the current coordinate system seems to be the width and height of an A4 in inches times the resolution of the printer.

8.26 inch x 1200 res = 9912
11.69 inch x 1200 res = 14028

I have tried the following but text just ended up huge.

```
auto page = printer.pageRect(QPrinter::Unit::Millimeter);
painter.setWindow(QRect(0, 0, page.width(), page.height()));
```

How do I change this so my QPainter can draw to 210 x 297 mm instead of the above system?

This is on Windows 10 and with Qt 5.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested this method on X11 (ubuntu linux) PDF print, using `ScreenResolution` printer mode:

```
painter.begin(printer);

int log_w  = 210;
int log_h  = 297;
painter.setWindow(0, 0, log_w, log_h);

int phys_w  = printer->width();
int phys_h = printer->height();
painter.setViewport(0, 0, phys_w, phys_h);
```

Basically, set your logical size in mm using the painter window, and give the painter's viewport the printer's  physical size.
This line should print a rectangle around the page with a border of 10 mm:

```
painter.drawRect(10, 10, log_w - 20, log_h -20);
```

Text should work accordingly. This code should print the word *Ok* at the top left corner of the rectangle:

```
  QFont font = painter.font();
  font.setPointSize(10); //1 cm height
  painter.setFont(font);
  painter.drawText(10, 20, "Ok");

  painter.end();
```

Using `HighResolution` printer mode, font size must be set using

```
font.setPixelSize(10); //1 cm height
```

and a `QPen` must be set to the painter:

```
QPen pen(Qt::black);
pen.setWidthF(0.2);
painter.setPen(pen);
painter.drawRect(10, 10, log_w - 20, log_h - 20);
```

About loss of device dependency using `setPixelSize`, I'm aware that [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html) is stated:

> It is possible to set the height of characters shown on the screen to
>   a specified number of pixels with setPixelSize(); however using
>   setPointSize() has a similar effect and provides device independence.

but I think it refers to screen only, given that [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#PrinterMode-enum) is stated:

> When rendering text on a QPrinter device, it is important to realize
>   that the size of text, when specified in points, is independent of the
>   resolution specified for the device itself. Therefore, it may be
>   useful to specify the font size in pixels when combining text with
>   graphics to ensure that their relative sizes are what you expect.

Comment: Hi, this method works partially for the rectangle and not at all for the text. Here is the minimal code example: https://pastebin.com/tT0ZLa87 which causes issues. When outputting to NativeFormat (Windows 10) the rectangle is correct, but the text is heavily inflated. When ouputting to pdf both are wrong. The PDFFormat output: http://g2f.nl/0o2if42 and the NativeFormat output: http://g2f.nl/0che686

Comment: When printing in high resolution (native printer) try setting the font size using. `setPixelSize`. About PDF, I really don't know, I'm using ScreenResolution as printer mode.

Comment: But that would be a device (dpi) dependent way of doing it. It seems like the font doesn't get transformed properly. I find it odd that it is this hard since this seems like a basic thing that you would want to do when printing.

Comment: I edited the answer for solving the PDF issue and address the device dependency concern.

Comment: Ok now I can get text drawn in the same size on both it's just very big now. How can I convert a pointsize as set in Adobe Illustrator to have the same size on the A4 in the drawing code. With the original window and viewport sizes it was a 1:1 mapping. Also my QSvgRenderer renderer("path"); will now show no output when calling renderer.render()

Comment: These are pretty much new questions, don't you think? I would post them separately, providing the relevamt code.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are looking for the [QTransform](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtransform.html#details) class, according to the official doc:

> The QTransform class specifies 2D transformations of a coordinate
>   system. A transformation specifies how to translate, scale, shear,
>   rotate or project the coordinate system, and is typically used when
>   rendering graphics.

You can initialise your custom transform class:

```
QTransform transform = QTransform::fromScale(painter.device()->physicalDpiX() / scale, painter.device()->physicalDpiY() / scale);
```

A think that this could be helpfull, the number of dots per militmeter:

```
const int dot_per_millimeter = qRound(qApp->primaryScreen()->physicalDotsPerInch() / 25.40);
```

Customise then your scale & apply it using a QPainter:

```
QPainter painter(parent);
painter.setWorldTransform(transform, false);
```

Comment: Using QTransform::fromScale(1.f / painter.device()->physicalDpiX(), 1.f / painter.device()->physicalDpiY()); just makes everything very small. I could scale it back up later, but it would be all pixely because it was painted at such a low resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct. Here is an example of how to set up a printer/painter pair. I don't fiddle around with the transformation matrix since it's sufficient to specify a window/viewport pair. I don't even specify the viewport explicitly, since it is automatically set to the metrics of the paint device (in this case the QPrinter object).

```
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QPainter>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::PrinterResolution);
    printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Portrait);
    printer.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize::A4));
    printer.setResolution(300 /*dpi*/);
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
    printer.setOutputFileName("ellipse.pdf");

    QPainter painter(&printer);

    auto page = printer.pageRect(QPrinter::Unit::Millimeter);
    painter.setWindow(page.toRect());

    // Draw a 5mm thick ellipse across the whole page.
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black, 5.0));
    painter.drawEllipse(0, 0, 210, 297);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the resulting pdf.]
It is hard to tell what goes wrong in your case without seeing the rest of the code

Comment: Hi, when using the example code you posted the ellipse is indeed stretched to the whole page, but when drawing some text it is oversized. Here is the code: https://pastebin.com/CFDWghKi and here is the ouput pdf: http://g2f.nl/0e905rh

Comment: Try setPixelSize() instead of setPointSize() and you should be ok.

Comment: But that would be a device (dpi) dependent way of doing it. It seems like the font doesn't get transformed properly. I find it odd that it is this hard since this seems like a basic thing that you would want to do when printing.

Comment: This is rather confusing stuff, with all the new different ways to implement HiDPI etc, but setPixelSize works for me, independent of the DPI of the document. Point Size is always going to be very platform dependent.